# Number of northeastern paths to (10,10) through (3,3) avoiding (5,5)

Tags: combinatorics

I will say I believe I have a correct solution to this problem, but I may be missing something and could use confirmation. The exact question is, "How many northeastern lattice paths (that is, where valid steps either increase the x coordinate by 1 or the y coordinate by 1) are there from $(0,0)$ to $(10,10)$ that do not pass through the point $(5,5)$, but do pass through the point $(3,3)$?"

I have already proven that the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ is ${n+k}\choose{n}$.

So the answer seems like it would simply be the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$ times the number of paths from $(3,3)$ to $(10,10)$ divided by the number of paths from $(3,3)$ to $(5,5)$, i.e.

${6}\choose{3}$ $\dfrac{{14}\choose{7}}{{4}\choose{2}} = 11440$

Is there some flaw in my reasoning, or is this correct?

Comment: Why divide? I think you should subtract the wrong paths from all paths in the second step.

Comment: Example: from (0,0) to (2,2) avoiding (1,1) there are two paths, while you are saying there would be 6/2=3. Instead you can count all paths (6) and subtract the wrong paths going from (0,0) via (1,1) to (2,2) (so 2*2=4) giving the right solution 6-4=2. Try the same approach for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that helps; I knew something seemed off. So the correct answer is (6 choose 3)*((14 choose 7) - (4 choose 2)*(10 choose 5))?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. And you're welcome!